# NET 6 Lambda : how to add roles to AWS Cognito?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I develop NET 6 AWS Lambda. I need add role-based access to controllers methods like

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SuperAdmin ")]
public class SecuredController : Controller
{}
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin ")]
public class LessSecuredController : Controller
{}
```

I use AWS Cognito. Where can set roles for users in AWS Cognito? and how they will be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Policy-based authorization`, which is very similar to `Role based authorization`.

To enable [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) with Cognito, you need to leverage **Cognito Groups**. This requires you to create a **Cognito group** first.

#### 1. Create a new Cognito group

1. Go to the Amazon Cognito console, and choose the user pool that you created earlier.
2. Choose the **Groups** tab, and then choose **Create a group**.
3. On the **Create a group** page, in Group name, enter **Admin** for your new group.
4. Leave everything with defaults.
5. Choose **Create** to confirm.

#### 2. Add user to the Cognito Group

1. Choose the **Users** tab, and then choose a user.
2. On the user detail page, scroll down to the bottom, and click on **Add user to group** button in **Group memberships** section.
3. Add the user to the previously created **Admin** group.

#### 3. Modifications in Code

After that, go to your **Program.cs** file, add the instructed code block in your file.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// ------ Add this code block -----
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("cognito:groups", "Admin"));
});
```

Finally, modify the `[Authorize]` attribute to include the policy name.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: If I understand  correctly: AWS Cognito  group == Role. For example, I need roles Admin, SuperAdmin, User then I create corresponding 3 groups. Correct?

Comment: 2. If the same user has Admin and PowerUser roles then I add the same user to both these groups ?

Comment: Yes for both. You can leverage AWS Groups to solve the purpose of Roles.

Comment: Done. please look at yet another my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75849999/net-6-lambda-aws-cognito-what-to-use-in-development