# NET 6 Lambda + AWS Cognito: what to use in development?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I develop NET 6 AWS Lambda. I need add role-based/policy-based access to controllers.
I use AWS Cognito. But what to use or how to be when I develop it on my local machine and run for the testing etc?
For example: I can do not use Authorize attributes when local machine, how to?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/cognito/

Comment: Do you mean unit testing? Run lambda as a normal method. The presence of attributes does not affect this in any way.

Comment: I have a NET 6 Lambda ->RDS PostgreSQL. It is web service will be used client apps. So iI develop it in my local environment VS2022, Swagger. local PostgreSQL db. I meant this case: do not use role permissions during the development on local machine